# Liferay 7 - I need to make the impersonate user URL dynamic

Tags: liferay, taglib

I am using the Custom Landing Page hook project (https://github.com/opensourceforlife/CustomLandingPage-Hook) to direct users to the private site of the organization they are associated with.  The hook works fine when the actual user logs in.

But I have a requirement to allow admins to impersonate users, which also works fine but can only be configured to open one specific page.

What I need is to have the URL change based on the logic of the custom landing page hook (logic that I can easily implement).  The result would be that the admin would end up on the correct page for the user they are impersonating.

I have looked into this, and the URL is generated by the <liferay-security:doAsURL> tag which is implemented in  com.liferay.taglib.security.DoAsURLTag.java

I am confident that I would be able to write the code to create the correct URL, however I am not sure how to overwrite the existing code.  I have done JSP hooks before, but I have never overwritten a taglib class (nor any class in an OSGI bundle - just JSPs).  I have to believe that this is possible, but I have yet to find any guidance for doing this (yes, I did look...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the tag's implementation, I'd recommend to replace the URL with a custom generated one (generate the right URL from the beginning) and change the JSP where the tag that you found is used.

AFAIK it's a single place where you can choose to impersonate a user, so the effort should be relatively low. As a positive side effect: Changing the tag implementation wouldn't automatically recompile a JSP, so that you might still end up with stale code (depending on the implementation nature of the tag, which I didn't look at).

Replacing the URL with a custom implementation should also be a lot easier and more straightforward than open heart surgery on a taglib.

Comment: I think you're right.  It seemed more elegant to replace the tag so that the change would be reflected everywhere it's used, but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere else (at least I didn't find it anywhere else). So that's what I'm going to do.